# Is it possible to add the same theme for the VS Code terminal as I use for the whole editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, themes

I just installed a new theme for my VS Code and the terminal looks out of place there.

Can I add the same theme for my terminal as the one I use for the editor? If I can't, then how can I change the colors of my terminal?

I am using VS Code 1.52.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can synchronize the terminal with the editor. There is an option that allows you to have a color scheme for the whole IDE rather than just the editor.